# How can I link Google Analytics to my iOS 8 App properly?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am trying to incorporate Google Analytics into my app. Following [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#idfa) tutorial, I have came across these errors:

```
//First Three errors
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAITrackedViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAITrackedViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o

//last error
ld: file not found: /path/to/libAdIdAccess.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
//
```

I have added

```
-force_load /path/to/libAdIdAccess.a
```

to my "other linker flags" section in my build settings to resolve the first three errors listed above. However, I am still left with the last error at the bottom. How can I fix this?

My app is running in iOS 8 and Xcode 6.

Comment: I've also tried restarting Xcode, cleaning my project. My framework search path is also empty.